# Can I interface with C++ objects from C without using an opaque pointer?

Tags: c++, c

This is an idea I thought of that maybe I could apply to my C project that currently interfaces with some C++ objects through opaque pointers. That's the usual way to do it, but dynamic allocation is unavoidable.

The following code shows my idea by using `std::mt19937` as an example. No dynamic allocation is needed, but some `#ifdef`s might be required for different language implementations.

```c
// C interface

typedef struct {
  // match sizeof and alignof std::mt19937
  // `#ifdef`s might be required
  alignas(8) char raw[5000];
} t_rand;

void rand_init(t_rand *, uint32_t);
void rand_fin(t_rand *);
uint32_t rand_gen_uint32(t_rand *);
```

```cpp
// C++ implementation

#include <memory>
#include <random>

void rand_init(t_rand *r, uint32_t seed) {
  static_assert(
    sizeof(t_rand) == sizeof(std::mt19937)
      && alignof(t_rand) == alignof(std::mt19937));
  std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<std::mt19937 *>(r), seed);
}

void rand_fin(t_rand *r) {
  std::destroy_at(reinterpret_cast<std::mt19937 *>(r));
}

uint32_t rand_gen_uint32(t_rand *r) {
  return (*reinterpret_cast<std::mt19937 *>(r))();
}
```

Is this a doable approach? If not, what are the problems, and what would be a better way? If it's okay, I'd also like to know if there's an actual project that uses the same pattern.

---

BTW, I think it was the wrong decision to set `result_type` or `std::mt19937` as `uint_fast32_t`, which is usually `uint64_t` on 64-bit platforms, to avoid zero/sign-extension. It should have been `uint_least32_t` to consume less memory and provide better L1 cache hits.

Comment: If you have a [POD structure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType) then it can be used as is from both C and C++.

Comment: Regarding the size of the array, it's implementation dependent. Different standard library implementations might have other sizes for their implementations.

Comment: You should use `int64_t` instead of `char`. This avoids the need for `alignas` and the problem when `char` isn't 8 bit.

Comment: Is that code actually better than an opaque pointer? Do you have code that needs to access the inside of the `t_rand` from the C side? I would replace `rand_init` with `rand_t * rand_alloc(uint32_t seed)` and keep it opaque.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I'm already using `sth_new(...)` with an opaque pointer, but thought maybe this could work. It seems to work with no problem in some simple cases. The one advantage of this approach is that dynamic allocation is not needed.

Comment: As Some programmer dude said it works for POD structures. Maybe more, I think anything with standard layout and you can static_assert that on the C++ side. I think the "no dynamic alocations" is dangerous for a struct that size unless you have it global. Eats up too much stack.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "Standard layout" seems to be quite restrictive than I thought [[1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class)]. Especially the requirement to have the same access control for all non-static data members. I'll need some time to analyze what it is, but it usually ends up avoiding C++ if possible.. As I mentioned in the post, the implementation or the specification of `std::mt19937` is wrong. It requires 2500 bytes in theory, but the current (glibc) implementation uses 5000, wasting space, causing problems like the one you said.

Comment: Since c++20 (iirc) the access control part should be gone as all members of a class are now layed out in the order specified regardless if of the access control. Compilers can no longer reorder variables with the same access control into blocks or other silly things. PS: If you want a data type with a known size use `uintX_t`. `uint_fastX_t` is for local variables you do lots of computations with, not for storage. And `uint_leastX_t` is practically for when you want to support systems where `char` might be bigger. I really only seen that on DSPs where you have 16bit `chars` and no `uint8_t`.